# Prove $f(n) = \frac{1 + (-1)^n(2n-1)}{4}$ surjects onto $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I need to prove that $f(n) = \frac{1 + (-1)^n(2n-1)}{4}$ where $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a surjection.

The book the problem is found in recommended I use two cases: one where f(n) is positive and one where it is negative.

I know I need to prove that for any arbitrary $ y \in \mathbb{Z}$ that there is a corresponding $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=y$.

However I am not sure how to do it for this function without proving a lemma.

Comment: Then prove that lemma. And if that's what causes you trouble, try explaining what lemma you're talking about and why you can't prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that

if $n=2k $ , $f (n)=k $ and

if $n=2k+1$, $f (n)=-k $

thus

for each $k\in \mathbb Z $,

there exists an  integer $n\in\mathbb N $

defined by

$n=2k \;\; $if $k\geq 0$ and

$n=1-2k  \;\;$ if $k\leq 0$ such that

$$f (n)=k $$
this is surjectivity.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I had used the cases where n = 2k and n = 2k + 1 to prove injectivity but didn't think to use it to prove surjectivity. Thanks!